# Connect to databricks using java sdk through proxy

Tags: java, proxy, sdk, databricks

I'm trying to connect to databricks from java using the java sdk and get cluster/sqlWarehouse state. I'm able to connect and get cluster state from my local. But, once I deploy it to the server, my company's network is not allowing the connection. We need to use proxy here but I'm not sure how to use proxy with the databricks java sdk.

Below is the code that works in local env:

DatabricksConfig config = new DatabricksConfig().setHost("https://name.databricks.com").setToken("myToken").resolve();

WorkspaceClient wc = new WorkspaceClient (config);
wc.clusters().get("myClusterId").getState().toString();

Any hint or suggestion would be helpful.